# Использование возможностей проекта Android C++ в Visual Studio

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2019, opengles

Недавно задался вопросом, как можно создавать **Android-приложение на языке C++**. Зайдя в **VS**, нашёл там **"Нативное приложение Android" на С++**. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Удачно скомпилировав и запустив его, решил попробовать изучить данную сборку. Но вот проблема - туториалов найти я не смог, документации тоже не видел. Возможно, плохо искал, но единственное, что смог понять - работает эта вещь на OpenGL ES. Поэтому хотел попросить помощи в этом вопросе.

*Вопрос:* Где я могу **найти документацию или книгу** по использованию возможностей данного проекта?

Сразу скажу, что знаю лишь базовый язык C++(могу понять что написано в коде), а с OpenGL почти не знаком.

Comment: [вот здесь например](https://tinyurl.com/y76qhzew)

Comment: @user7860670 Видел, но мне нужна документация именно по этому проекту. В msdn описан лишь способ запуска, а в developer.android.com описан Android Studio, а я ищу именно для VS. Возможно, я что-то не понимаю, так что поправьте.

Comment: developer.android.com описан android SDK, который используется как в Android Studio, так и в Visual Studio

Comment: Так SDK - это Java. А мне C++ нужен. Хотя бы понять что конкретно выполняет код и зачем, ибо функции в файле main.cpp никогда ранее не видел.

Comment: На андроиде действительно большая часть API на java. Однако SDK - это полный набор ресурсов для разработки под платформу.

Comment: Дело в том, что я по-прежнему не понимаю, что мне нужно прочитать чтобы потом я смог спокойно писать код в данном проекте на С++. На developer описана лишь Java. Я ведь почему на С++ хочу писать - такие приложения быстрее работают. Да и Java учить желания нет.

Comment: *"На developer описана лишь Java."* - это не правда... ¿Вы хоть пробовали искать там *"функции в файле main.cpp никогда ранее не видел"*? "*Да и Java учить желания нет.*" - а придется, так как большинство API на андроиде доступны именно на java. Собственно все приложения, включающие в себя взаимодействие с пользователем, обязательно задействуют java на каком-то уровне, в том числе и "Нативное приложение android", проект которого на скриншоте. Благо обладая знанием c++ освоить java совсем не сложно.

Comment: "_Вы хоть пробовали искать там_"
- Да, пробовал, и не нашёл, повторюсь - я очень плохо ищу.
" _а придется, так как большинство API на андроиде доступны именно на java_"
- Мне и OpenGL для начала хватит. Но я так понимаю что Android - это только Java, если не использовать движки, так что пойду изучать. Спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: @user7860670, а разве с помощью NativeActivity не получится написать приложение под Андроид в том числе с функциями взаимодействия с пользователем только на С++ без Java ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Ну как сказать, формально проект можно написать на C++ и даже на C. Однако там будет постоянное взаимодействие с Java - неявное посредством оберток из NDK либо явное посредством jni.

Comment: @user7860670, ну я это и имел ввиду, что nativeactivity вроде бы внутри использует тот же JNI, но скрывает его от програмиста и сам код на Java не нужно писать, а можно использовать только с++. Это я к тому, что Вы написали, что java учить придется, но теоретически с nativactivity, в этом не должно быть необходимости.

Comment: @Optimus1 Писать может придется на С++, но без приличного знания java ничего толкового написать не удастся.

Comment: @user7860670, а как в данном случае связаны знания Java и написания кода полностью на С/С++ ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Я же уже написал выше - **Однако там будет постоянное взаимодействие с Java - неявное посредством оберток из NDK либо явное посредством jni.**